# Spark reduceByKey on several different values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table stored as an RDD of lists, on which I want to perform something akin to a groupby in SQL or pandas, taking the sum or average for every variable.

The way I currently do it is this (untested code):

```
l=[(3, "add"),(4, "add")]
dict={}
i=0
for aggregation in l:
    RDD= RDD.map(lambda x: (x[6], float(x[aggregation[0]])))
    agg=RDD.reduceByKey(aggregation[1])
    dict[i]=agg
    i+=1
```

Then I'll need to join all the RDDs in dict.

This isn't very efficient though. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using >= Spark 1.3, you could look at the [DataFrame API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame).

In the pyspark shell:

```
import numpy as np
# create a DataFrame (this can also be from an RDD)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(map(lambda x:map(float, x), np.random.rand(50, 3)))
df.agg({col: "mean" for col in df.columns}).collect()
```

This outputs:

```
[Row(AVG(_3#1456)=0.5547187588389414, AVG(_1#1454)=0.5149476209374797, AVG(_2#1455)=0.5022967093047612)]
```

The available aggregate methods are "avg"/"mean", "max", "min", "sum", "count".

To get several aggregations for the same column, you can call `agg` with a list of explicitly constructed aggregations rather than with a dictionary:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.agg(*[F.min(col) for col in df.columns] + [F.avg(col) for col in df.columns]).collect()
```

Or for your case:

```
df.agg(F.count(df.var3), F.max(df.var3), ) # etc...
```

Comment: Could you enlighten me on the syntax to have specific aggregate methods for specific variables. Currently the below only gives me the last method I used for each variable:

aggreg=df1.filter(df1.var3>25).join(df2, df1.Machine== df2.Machine).groupBy(df1.Machine).agg({"var3":"count","var3":"max","var4":"mean","var4":"max","var5":"mean","var6":"mean"})

Comment: Thanks. With this new syntax, the groupby variable (Machine in this case) vanishes though. How can I keep it?